# Optimal pairing algorithm with few-value integer data

Tags: algorithm, optimization, string-matching, similarity

I have to compare 2 strings, say, `CDABAB` and `EABACCCBB`. For me, the similarity is simply the amount of co-occurence of the same characters in both, regardless the position (i.e. the strings are "texts" not "sequences"). In addition, characters that form a co-occuring chain of characters, are given double weight.

In my example, `A`, `A`, `B`, `B`, `C` are the instances of co-occurence. Also, `ABA` is a chain with 3 characters to double-weight. So, `A(2)`, `A(2)`, `B(2)`, `B(1)`, `C(1)` to sum, `2+2+2+1+1=8` is the similarity between the two strings for me. The example was too easy; in real life I have strings of a thousand+ lengths. So I need an algorithm.

This is clearly a classic assignment problem. And I know it can be solved by, for example, [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). We should construct matrix of co-occurence (2 = double weight because of a chain):

```
   E A B A C C C B B
C          1 1 1
D
A    2   1  
B      2         1 1
A    2   2
B      2         1 1
```

and pair rows and columns one-to-one optimally so that the sum of within-pair similarities is maximized. It implies leaving only one positive value in each row and column, in a way giving the maximal matrix sum of values. Hungarian algorithm is a general approach that will give such maximal sum (the optimal solution). The left entries have the sum `8`, same to what is computed above:

[image]

However, Hungarian is not particularly fast (and not quite easy to program). I need another algorithm with my long strings. **Can you suggest me another algorithm, faster and desirably easier**? Note that my data are special case: it is **similarity matrix with 3 integer values only - 0, 1, and 2**.

(With binary matrix, it is very easy to make the optimal pairing. With 3 values, I have an idea how to do, but it can give suboptimal, albeit "good" solution, in terms of exactness. Is there a way to always get the optimal one?)

**P.S. Important.** My elements in strings are actually not real characters from a limited alphabet, but are real words; so - they come from potentially unlimited alphabet which I don't know beforehand. I will not do preprocessing such as frequency counting. I'm rather inclined to start  with the rectangular matrix as shown above: I can make such a matrix with proper 0,1,2 values quite efficiently. My main question is about further algorithm.

Thank you (for your patience, too).

---

**Later update: a reply** to @j_random_hacker's answer.

I liked the proposed quick approach, it looked handsome. But I've found that it is problematic. The example below demonstrates it.

```
Two strings are
S1= ABCACCDECF
S2= BACBCCDA

The matrix of co-occurences (where chains are given weight 2) is therefore:
   B  A  C  B  C  C  D  A
A  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1* 
B  1  0  0  2* 0  0  0  0 
C  0  0  1  0  2* 1  0  0 
A  0  2* 0  0  0  0  0  1 
C  0  0  2* 0  2  1  0  0 
C  0  0  1  0  1  2* 0  0 
D  0  0  0  0  0  0  2* 0 
E  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
C  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0 
F  0* 0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Hungarian algorithm of optimal pairing paired the rows and columns so as to maximize
the sum of within-pair values. These values - which pair a row and a column - are shown starred
in the matrix. And the sum is 13. It is the "similarity" between the strings.

Let us compute now the similarity by the quick algorithm suggested by @j_random_hacker.

Counts of individual characters (only occuring in both strings shown):
     A  B  C  D
S1   2  1  4  1
S2   2  2  3  1
---------------
Min  2  1  3  1
Sum1=7

Counts of dyadic chains (only occuring in both strings shown):
     BC  AC  CC  CD
S1    1   1   1   1
S2    1   1   1   1
-------------------
Min   1   1   1   1
Sum2=4

Counts of triadic chains (only occuring in both strings shown):
     CCD
S1    1
S2    1
--------
Min   1
Sum3=1

Sum1 + 2Sum2 - Sum3 = 14. While I was expecting 13, as Hungarian algo gave.

The cause of the discrepancy seems obvious enough.
The second algorithm recognized 4 dyads: AC, BC, CD, and CC; and because CC and CD actually
superimpose by C (they form a triad CCD), C should be counted only once as a member of a dyad.

However, as seen from the starred elements in the matrix, Hungarian algorithm recognized
only 3 dyads: AC, BC, CD. Because the first of the two C is shared by by AC and CC or by
BC and CC, this character is (since it cannot be counted twice) is discarded altogether,
and hence the dyad it is a member of, CC, does not exist. And that is correct for me.
```

Comment: What do you mean by suboptimal solution? In terms of speed or in terms of exactness?

Comment: Exactness - sum isn't the maximal possible.

Comment: What is "co-occurrence"?  How are you going to interpret the result?

Comment: @tmyklebu The fact that a character is present in _both_ strings. That is, the instance of nonzero value in the matrix. However the instances are surplus, and only one nonzero value in each row and each column of the matrix counts, in the end. The task is - to select those values which sum is maximal.

Comment: @ttnphns: Huh?  C is present in both strings.

Comment: @tmyklebu, So what? `C` finds once in one, and thrice in the other, so the similarity between the strings by `C` is only 1.

Comment: "I will not do preprocessing such as frequency counting" -- constructing your matrix requires *vastly* more memory and time than 3 linear-size frequency tables, even before applying the Hungarian algorithm.  Separately, it's not at all clear how you intend to efficiently decide whether a nonzero matrix element should be 1 or 2.

Comment: @ttnphns: But it's present in both strings.  Why doesn't it get a 2?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I construct my matrix by matrix (arrays) operations. I first create the binary matrix and then change some 1's to 2's, the latter is done by shifting the matrix diagonally by one element over itself with proper summation of superimposed elements. It is quick, and I have enough RAM. So the matrix isn't a problem for me. My question focuses on what to undertake next with it.

Comment: @tmyklebu, Because _one_ `C` can find itself only one counterpart in `CCC` (or `C` or `CCCCCCCCC`). If there were `CC` vs `CCC`, then there is chain match, and weight 2 would be applied instead of 1.

Comment: Using the matrix as you describe is O(n^2) in space and O(n^3) in time (the worst case will occur when both strings are one long sequence of the same word, repeated n times), compared to my proposal which is O(n) for each.  Yours will be from hundreds to millions of times slower for strings with lengths of 1000 or so, depending on how repetitious your strings are.  If something about my algorithm isn't clear, just ask.

Comment: `the worst case will occur when both strings are one long sequence of the same word` I shift the matrix one element up-left and one element down-right, only. Because I don't need to measure the lengths of chains. Any chain of length >=2 gets the same weight 2. Please look in my matrix.

Comment: Ah, you're right -- your current algorithm is only O(n^2).  I won't say it again, but O(n) is still better!

Comment: @j_random_hacker, One more notion. I do programming _not_ in a low level language (such as C or Fortran), but in a package-specific syntax (such as Matlab's), with interpreted loop facility which is, of course, only moderately fast. On the other hand, those matrix functions of the syntax, which I use, are built on C or Fortran and are fast. Therefore it is not quite correct to predict speed as you do it, in my situation.

Comment: It may be that your strings are small enough that it's faster to use your approach, but for sufficiently long strings that will not be the case.  In any case, I think Matlab has fast/compact sparse matrices -- if so then you can encode each word as a numeric index, and hold the frequency vectors in sparse vectors instead of hashtables.  Then calculating A, B and C can be done using Matlab's fast internal C/Fortran implementations of min() and addition on these vectors instead of handwritten loops.

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT 23/7/2014: This answer is incorrect -- see the OP's counterexample at the top.]**

Actually this isn't the Assignment Problem at all.

Preprocess each string S as follows:

1. For each letter X, count the frequency of X in S and store it in f1[S][X].
2. For each pair of adjacent letters XY, count the frequency of XY in S and store it in f2[S][XY].
3. For each triple of adjacent letters XYZ, count the frequency of XYZ in S and store it in f3[S][XYZ].

(See below for a possible speedup.)

**[EDIT: Fixed the formula below to count *each* letter in a shared letter pair.]**

The similarity of any pair of strings S and T is then given by A + 2B - C, where

```
A = sum(min(f1[S][X],   f1[T][X]))   over all letters X
B = sum(min(f2[S][XY],  f2[T][XY]))  over all letter pairs XY
C = sum(min(f3[S][XYZ], f3[T][XYZ])) over all letter triples XYZ
```

A calculates the number of letters shared by S and T, B the number of adjacent letter-pairs, and C corrects for cases where 2 shared adjacent pairs overlap by 1 letter (e.g. if S and T are both `ABC`, then A = 3, B = 2 (since `AB` and `BC` appear in both strings) and C = 1, so that the `B` shared by those 2 pairs doesn't get counted twice.)

If the alphabet size is large, there may be many letter pairs and even more triples.  In that case you can add "that occur at least once in S" or "that occur at least once in T" to the end of each line defining A, B and C -- that is, it suffices to scan forward through one of the strings, looking at every (unique) letter, letter pair and letter triple that occurs in it.  This changes the comparison algorithm from being cubic in the alphabet size to  linear in the length of the smaller string.  Similarly, in the preprocessing phase you could store only the letters, pairs and triples that actually occur in S in f1[S], f2[S] and f3[S] using hashtables instead of plain arrays.

Comment: Thank you. However, my immediate reaction is doubt, sorry. (Perhaps I may think it back later.) Your proposal seems reasonable in terms of time if I know the _alphabet_ (the list of possible characters) in advance or could know it quickly from the data by content analysis. In my case, the alphabet is potentially unlimited (my "characters" are actually real _words_) and I won't do preliminary frequency counting.

Comment: In that case, use the suggestion in the last paragraph to make both the preprocessing and the comparisons linear in the length of the string(s).

Comment: Suppose a string S has n words.  If you apply the idea in my last paragraph, f1[S] will be a hashtable containing at most n (word, freq) entries (fewer if some words were repeated in S), f2[S] will contain at most n-1 entries (fewer if some word pairs were repeated), and f3[S] will contain at most n-2 entries (fewer if some word triples were repeated).  Altogether this will require at most a small multiple of the space needed to hold S itself.

Comment: I've got across some problem with your solution, though. Can you look into the addendum to the question?

Comment: I see now that I had misunderstood, and yes my algorithm is wrong.  I have a new idea, which I'll try to write up in a day or two, but in the meantime here's a quick improvement: notice that there must be exactly `A` edges in any optimal solution; the task is to make as many of them 2-edges (instead of 1-edges) as possible.  Therefore it's enough to apply the Hungarian Algorithm to *just the 2-edges*, count the number of edges this produces, and then add `A` to this number: this will count all 2-edges in the solution twice, and all the others once :)

Comment: It just appeared to me that in my intuitive concept of similarity I'm not to be necessarily bound by the Hungarian maximized sum. I'm begining to think that instead of 3 dyads `AC, BC, CD` (sum is 12) I might prefer to count a triad and 2 (with weight 2) singletons `CCD, A, B` (sum is 10). It is reasonable that the longest common substring is appreciated in the first place. What do you think? On the other hand, in _this_ particular example I'd perhaps not prefer the triad - because it has the same character/word `C` in succession.

Comment: Well, I think the score my original algorithm calculates is useful -- a similar n-gram approach underlies many bioinformatics similarity-search algorithms -- but ultimately, deciding how to score is up to you.  Your maximum-matching approach is also useful, though as you say, if you want to give pairs of strings that share long common substrings higher scores than strings that don't, it won't necessarily achieve this.

Comment: I liked your posted (the "wrong") algo because I found I can expand its formula from 0,1,2 weights to any number 0,1,...,W weights (ask me if you are interested in it). This encouraged me because I thought that I'd like to have arbitrary max weight W. If you will be posting a new or reviced algo of yours, please take that into consideration. Meanwile, fortune to you.